# Server-side c# and client side javascript with json loading Highcharts gantt chart Task Progress Indicator, need to change Tooltip and Label name

Tags: javascript, highcharts

JsFiddle of Gantchart [Taskprogress Indicator](https://jsfiddle.net/sanlak/zatc2q1n/2/)

Refer the Image

[image]

How to configure the **Label name** and also change the **Tooltip**.

```
var markers = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString("GetTaskWorkPercentage","2",null,1,10) %>');
var Arrayset = [];
var starts1 = [];
var ends1 = [];
var val1 = [];
var val2 = [];

if (markers != null) {
    if (markers.length > 0) {
        var prj = document.getElementById("param1").value;
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

            var syearval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualStart.substr(0, 4));
            var smonthval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualStart.substr(5, 2)) - 1;
            var sdateval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualStart.substr(8, 2));

            var eyearval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualEnd.substr(0, 4));
            var emonthval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualEnd.substr(5, 2)) - 1;
            var edateval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualEnd.substr(8, 2));
            val1 = [Date.UTC(syearval, smonthval, sdateval)];
            val2 = [Date.UTC(eyearval, emonthval, edateval)];
            starts1.push(val1[0]);
            ends1.push(val2[0]);
            Arrayset.push({
                name: markers[i].Task,
                completed: markers[i].Percentages,
                start: starts1[i],
                end: ends1[i]
            });
        }

        MainLoadChart(Arrayset);
    }
}
```

```
function MainLoadChart(array) {
    var dta = array;
    Highcharts.ganttChart('container8', {

        title: {
            text: 'Task Progress Indicator Status'
        },

        series: [{
            name: prj,
            ** javascript array **

            data: dta,
            ** javascript array **

        }]

    });
}
```

In the task progress how to show the LABEL name and how to add "Overall Subtasks Percentage" in the tooltip near to **Feature 1.1.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *In the task progress how to show the LABEL name*

You can change the **dataLabel** value by using the formatter callback.

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    data: [{
      name: 'Start prototype',
      start: Date.UTC(2019, 10, 18),
      end: Date.UTC(2020, 04, 13),
      completed: 283.33,
    }],
    dataLabels: {
      formatter() {
        return this.point.name
      }
    }
  }]
```

- *how to add "Overall Subtasks Percentage" in the tooltip near to Feature 1.1.2*

To customize tooltip or add any new value use the formatter callback.

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter() {
      let output = `<span style="font-size: 10px">${this.point.series.name}</span><br>
      <span><b>${this.key} + some custom value</b></span><br>
      <span>Start: ${Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %e. %b, %Y', this.x)}</span><br>
      <span>End: ${Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %e. %b, %Y', this.x2)}</span>`            
      return output
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9g1rvhb2/

---

API: https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/tooltip.formatter

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats.day

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: series: [{
    data: dta,
     dataLabels: {
           formatter() {
                           return this.point.completed
                               
                         }
                   },

}]            Task progress label is not showing. Its showing blank. Check the code i added

Comment: Both working. Thanks. I have made a mistake in my side